# UI Automation of Microsoft Dynamic AX

Tags: c#, user-interface, ui-automation, microsoft-dynamics

I looking to try and automate UI tests of Microsoft Dynamics AX (All Versions). I intend on using free and open source tools only.

What framework is the UI of Microsoft Dynamics AX built in? I had heard it may be WPF but I had had no luck so far as to finding much information around this.

I have tried using autoit but it cannot find controls as I expected.
I have tried using the microsoft UI automation stuff and using patterns found by Inspect but I get errors running when running the code saying the pattern is unsupported and it has no supported patters.

Has anyone had any experiance in trying to do this or has anyone got any information around this, anything may prove to be useful.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

[Teststack.White](http://teststack.net/White/) tool may be useful though it's based on the Microsoft UI Automation API.

Comment: Thank you for your resonse, I have tried your suggestion but it doesnt seem to be able to pick up the controls either. Really stuck on this...